# How to detect a UDP flow completion?

Tags: udp

I'm working on a project of client/server form. In the the project I need to check both TCP and UDP flow if they are finished or not.
Since UDP has no FIN bit,is there a simple way to detect whether a UDP flow is completed or not?

Comment: Since UDP has no FIN bit, there is no such thing as a UDP flow. If you want it, you have to implement it yourself in your application protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to detect the end of UDP is add some extro information in UDP packets. For example, we can add a FIN flag in the final packet.

The better way is to add a header part in UDP packets, so that you can do lots of things like controling the end of UDP flows or limiting the speed. That is how reliable UDP works.

Comment: Assuming the application protocol also has sequencing.